# How do i hide the currency symbol when there is no input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

So i am making a create product page. The items were product name, product price, product description. There are gonna be times where user doesnt want to input any price on their product just yet. In that case i dont want it to show currency with the value 0 on the page. Is there any way to hide the currency? thank you

```
const [price, setPrice] = useState();

  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("id-ID", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "IDR",
  });

<p className="card-text">{formatter.format(item.price)}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition to check the empty value of `item.price` on your JSX like below

```
<p className="card-text">{Boolean(item.price) && formatter.format(item.price)}</p>
```

If you want to reuse that formatter for other values, I'd suggest you introduce a function

```
const formatCurrency = (priceValue) => {
   if(!priceValue) {
     return '';
   }

   return new Intl.NumberFormat("id-ID", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "IDR",
  });
}

<p className="card-text">{formatCurrency(item.price)}</p>
```